# calculo el producto escalar pero el resultado no es el correcto

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
int producto_escalar(int a[],int b[],int m){
int resultado=0;
for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
    resultado=resultado+(a[i]*b[i]);
}
return resultado;

}
int multio(int bmd,int amd){
return bmd*amd;
}
int multiplicar (int am,int bm){
return am*bm;
}

int main()
{
    int m,am,bm,amd,bmd;
    int a[m],b[m];
    printf("inserte la cantidad de componentes que quiere en los arreglos: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("ingrese el valor de %d para el arreglo a: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if(i==0){
            am=a[i];
        }
        if(i==1){
            amd=a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("ingrese el valor de %d para el arreglo b: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        if (i==m-1){
            bm=b[i];
        }
        if (i==m-2){
            bmd=b[i];
        }
    }
    printf("el ultimo elemento de b es: %d\n", bm);
    printf("el primer elemento de a es: %d\n", am);
    printf("el resultado de la multiplicacion de los elementos es: %d\n",multiplicar(am,bm));
    printf("el penultimo elemento de b es: %d\n",bmd);
    printf("el segundo elemento de a es: %d\n",amd);
    printf("el resultado de la multiplicacion de los elementos es:%d\n",multio(bmd,amd));
    printf("el resultado del producto escalar es: %d",producto_escalar(a,b,m));
    return 0;
}
```

despues de realizar todos los calculos lo ultimo que me faltaba era calcular el producto escalar, realice las invocaciones y con la formula y no tira basura, pero si tira un resultado superior al correcto y no veo porque puede ser, la multiplicacion de los valores de la componente de los arreglos me da bien por separado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C las variables se *crean* en el mismo momento en el que se declaran. Así, en la siguiente línea:

```
int a[m],b[m];
```

Se crean dos arrays, `a` y `b`, ambos de tamaño `m`. ¿problemas? varios:

- `m` es una variable no inicializada, luego el tamaño de los arrays será un misterio. ¿Y si `m` tuviese un tamaño negativo en este punto? ¿o 0? Da igual que modifiques el valor de `m` posteriormente, los arrays se crearán en este punto y su tamaño no cambiará en ningún momento.
- `a[m]` es un VLA o *Variable Length Array* y es una característica no soportada por el estándar, es decir, es algo que algunos compiladores soportan pero otros no. No es una práctica recomendable
- Tanto `a` como `b` se están creando en la pila, si `m` fuese muy grande se podría desbordar la pila del programa.
- En C los arrays no controlan sus límites, es decir, nadie se va a preocupar de si accedes al elemento 1.000 en un array de únicamente 5 elementos. Es tu responsabilidad no exceder los límites del array. Esto lo comento porque existe aproximadamente un 50% de posibilidades de que `m` sea negativo, en cuyo caso el tamaño final de los arrays será un misterio.

  Si, por ejemplo, ambos arrays se creasen con tamaño 0 o 1, entonces la memoria de ambos se solaparía y eso explicaría el comportamiento errático que tu estás encontrando

La solución a estos problemas pasa por usar memoria dinámica:

```
int m;
printf("inserte la cantidad de componentes que quiere en los arreglos: ");
scanf("%d",&m);

int *a = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
int *b = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
    printf("ingrese el valor de %d para el arreglo a: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    if(i==0){
        am=a[i];
    }
    if(i==1){
        amd=a[i];
    }
}

// ...

// Liberamos la memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria
free(a);
free(b);
```